# getIFPPlanQuotes - what is InsuranceEffectiveDate?

Tags: medical, healthcare-finder-api

Why are my results different when I change the InsuranceEffectiveDate field? For example in the below request I changed the InsuranceEffectiveDate from `2015-01-01` to `2016-03-01` and received 50 less plans. I expected the field to represent when a insurance can start to insure you, which should lead to a increase of plans for future dates, but I saw the opposite result. How does a effective date make sense to be in the past?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:PlanQuoteRequest xmlns:p="http://hios.cms.org/api" xmlns:p1="http://hios.cms.org/api-types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://hios.cms.org/api hios-api-11.0.xsd ">
  <p:Enrollees>
    <p1:DateOfBirth>1990-01-01</p1:DateOfBirth>
    <p1:Gender>Male</p1:Gender>
    <p1:TobaccoLastUsedMonths>0</p1:TobaccoLastUsedMonths>
    <p1:Relation>SELF</p1:Relation>
    <p1:InHouseholdIndicator>true</p1:InHouseholdIndicator>
  </p:Enrollees>
  <p:Location>
    <p1:ZipCode>10075</p1:ZipCode>
    <p1:County>
      <p1:FipsCode>36061</p1:FipsCode>
      <p1:CountyName>NEW YORK</p1:CountyName>
      <p1:StateCode>NY</p1:StateCode>
    </p1:County>
  </p:Location>
  <p:InsuranceEffectiveDate>2015-01-01</p:InsuranceEffectiveDate>
  <p:Market>Individual</p:Market>
  <p:IsFilterAnalysisRequiredIndicator>false</p:IsFilterAnalysisRequiredIndicator>
  <p:PaginationInformation>
    <p1:PageNumber>1</p1:PageNumber>
    <p1:PageSize>500</p1:PageSize>
  </p:PaginationInformation>
  <p:SortOrder>
    <p1:SortField>BASE RATE</p1:SortField>
    <p1:SortDirection>ASC</p1:SortDirection>
  </p:SortOrder>
</p:PlanQuoteRequest>
```